# Nested Loop Explanation needed

Tags: nested-loops

This is a very basic question but haven't been able to find a clear explanation. Why does the below code give 30 as a result for k?

I just would like to understand the mechanism, but for some reason, I cannot get my head around this. I know we first start looking at the inner for loop - we get 10 iterations until number2 reaches 10 (and k becomes 10, number 1 becomes 24. But what's next?

```
int number1(4), number2, k = 0;
        while (number1 < 10) 
        {
            for (number2 = 1; number2 <= 10; number2++)
                ++k;
                number1 = number1 + 2; 
    }
        cout << k << endl;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
number1 = number1 + 2;
```

is not in the inner loop. Assuming C/C++, if you don't wrap the code inside the loops with curly braces, only the first line after the loop directive gets evaluated as the loop code.

What happens in a single outer loop iteration is as follows:

1. The inner loop runs 10 times.
2. `k` gets incremented 10 times.
3. You drop to the outer loop. `number1` gets incremented by 2.

The outer loop repeats 3 times.  Thus `k` gets incremented 3 x 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

I added brackets to the code below.

It is the same as the code above, but alittle more clear.

```
int number1(4), number2, k = 0;
    while (number1 < 10) 
    {
        for (number2 = 1; number2 <= 10; number2++)
        {                                             //Added the brackets
            ++k;
        }                        
        number1 = number1 + 2; 
}
    cout << k << endl;
```

Your indentation is goofy